# using ClientWebSocket when trying to SendAsync it throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, websocket

After I connected to ws when I try to send message to server it throw exception. I have tried that lots of diffirent way (with async, in xamarin.forms aplication). I am always getting same issue.Any idea what is a problem?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IlVu.jpg)

Edit: Problem has solved.
I checked connection status with "Console.WriteLine(conn.State)" I seen that it was still connecting so after connection method I have applied time delay "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)" and problem has solved. So Problem occur because of uncompleted connection.

Comment: Are you sure the connection completed?  Check the connection status from cmd.exe >Netstat -a

Comment: I checked connection status with "Console.WriteLine(conn.State)" I seen that it was still connecting so after connection method I have applied time delay "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)" and problem has solved. So Problem occur because of uncompleted connection. Thanks.